# GPU and CPU support for Fedora Linux?

Tags: graphics-cards, linux, development, processor

I have three specific questions:

- AMD vs Nvidia: Which company has the most painless graphics drivers? I would prefer to avoid compiling drivers, but if that's required, I will do it.
- Is a GPU necessary for development work? Would a low-end GPU be acceptable, or would it be best to have a mid-range (like an RX480)?
- How's the Ryzen 7 support on Fedora as of now?